# Cython: undefined symbol

Tags: python, cython

I wrote a minimal C function (with accompanying header file) with the goal of creating a Cython wrapper that would enable the C code's use from a Python file somewhere else.

My files are as such:

C file:

```
/* engine.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include "customlib.h"

int engine(int value, int iterations) {

    /* declare iteration index */
    int idx;

    for (idx = 0; idx < iterations; idx = idx + 1) {
        value = value * 3;
    }

    /* return value that should be accessible by the Python module */
    return value;
}
```

C header file:

```
/* customlib.h */

#ifndef CUSTOM_HEADER_H
#define CUSTOM_HEADER_H

/* engine function */
int engine(int value, int iterations);

#endif
```

Cython module that wraps the C code:

```
# wrapper.pyx

cdef extern from "customlib.h":
    int engine(int value, int iterations)

def call_c_code(value, iterations):
    output_value = engine(value, iterations)
    print(output_value)
```

Python module that calls the C code via the Cython wrapper:

```
# caller.py

import wrapper

wrapper.call_c_code(1, 2) /* values not important; just an example */
```

Setup code for generating the *.so from the *.pyx file:

```
# setup.py

from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

# definitions
sourcefiles = ['engine.c']
extensions = [Extension('wrapper', sourcefiles)]

# setup function
setup(name='wrapper', ext_modules=cythonize('wrapper.pyx'))
```

THE PROBLEM: The shared object (*.so) seems to compile without any issues. However, even just importing the `wrapper.py` throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "caller.py", line 10, in <module>
    import wrapper
ImportError: /home/alex/Documents/Projects/Cython/wrapper.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: engine
```

Comment: Try to setup.py add sourcefiles = ['engine.c',]
extensions = [Extension("wrapper", sourcefiles)]
setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions)
)

Comment: @AndrejKesely same error, unfortunately

Comment: @questionable_code I tried your provided code and this helped me to get rid of `undefined symbol` message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `setup.py` you don't actually do anything with:

```
extensions = [Extension('wrapper', sourcefiles)]
```

this is just dead code, essentially.   It assigns to a variable and then never uses it.  Regardless, you don't want to make an `Extension` from your `engine.c`.  `Extension` is for defining Python modules.  The only Python module here is the one compiled from `wrapper.pyx`.

Instead, try something like:

```
extensions = [Extension('wrapper', ['wrapper.pyx', 'engine.c'])]
setup(
    ...
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions)
    ...
 )
```

This will also compile `engine.c` and link its resulting object file into your extension module.

The `cythonize` helper function is smart enough to distinguish plain `.c` sources from Cython sources that it needs to pass through the Cython compiler.  It will then pass all the resulting C sources through the C compiler and link them.

Comment: You're right. I edited it errantly at an earlier suggestion (which was a good suggestion, I just typed it out incorrectly). You provided the full-form answer with the correct implementation, so thank you very much! :)